# Android Studio CodeEditText why not working?

Tags: java, android

https://github.com/lukelorusso/CodeEditText 
https://github.com/lukelorusso/CodeEditText/blob/master/press/demo2.gif

Hi,
the source i found is exactly as i wanted but after i apply it Android Studio freezes "." Classes and Functions that follow are not shown. Does anyone know the solution. or how can I do any other solution suggestions?

I think the problem is that I am trying to integrate the Kotlin library while using java, but it says that it can be used in the article.

Let me tell you once again exactly what I want to do. I want to create edittext according to the words first and then the letters of the incoming sentence. then whenever a value is entered in each edittex, I want it to send it to the other edittex. At the end of the process, I will check whether the sentence is the same with the entered value.

Thank you from now.

Comment: do you have any error logs documenting what the error could be?

Comment: maalesef Code EditText nesnesini oluşturduktan sonra nesnenin özellikleri gelmiyor ve devam edemiyorum. Aslında daha doğrusu androidStudio kilitleniyor.